How to remove healthfitness module and apex in android 14?
On Android 14, the healthfitness module is turned on by default, but on some special machines this is redundant, how do I get rid of these things?
In the process of compiling, I have tried to delete him directly at the end of the PRODUCT_PACKAGES, the deletion of the contents are
HealthConnectBackupRestore .
HealthConnectBackupRestore.com.android.healthfitness .
HealthConnectController.
HealthConnectController.com.android.healthfitness .
com.android.healthfitness
But this will lead directly to a compilation error
